# SQL Value Repetition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

All,

This may be easy but I need some help.

I currently have a query which returns these results:

```
Transaction ID | Date     | Product Code | Tranaction Type | Customer ID
-------------- | ---------| ------------ | --------------- | -----------
1              | 20170810 | X1           | T               | 1000 0000 0000 0001
1              | 20170810 | X2           | I               |
1              | 20170810 | X3           | I               |
```

I would like to know how I can add the Customer ID on each of the transaction lines?

Please see below my current query

```
SELECT 
DAILYSALES.INTTRANSNUM AS [TRANSACTION ID],
Convert(CHAR(8), DTMSALEDATETIME, 112) AS [DATE], 
dbo.DAILYSALES.LINTITEMNUMBER AS [PRODUCT CODE], 
DAILYSALES.STRCOMMENT AS [CUSTOMER ID]

FROM dbo.DAILYSALES (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN ITEM (NOLOCK) ON DAILYSALES.LINTITEMNUMBER = ITEM.LINTITEMNUMBER


WHERE 
(DAILYSALES.DTMTRADEDATE >= GETDATE()-2 AND DRSDATA.dbo.DAILYSALES.DTMTRADEDATE <= GETDATE())
AND (STRSALETYPE IN ('I','T'))
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT ds.INTTRANSNUM AS [TRANSACTION ID],
       Convert(CHAR(8), DTMSALEDATETIME, 112) AS [DATE], 
       ds.LINTITEMNUMBER AS [PRODUCT CODE], 
       ds.STRCOMMENT AS [CUSTOMER ID],
       MAX(ds.STRCOMMENT) OVER (PARTITION BY ds.INTTRANSNUM) as customer_id
FROM dbo.DAILYSALES ds LEFT JOIN
     ITEM i 
     ON ds.LINTITEMNUMBER = i.LINTITEMNUMBER
WHERE ds.DTMTRADEDATE >= GETDATE() - 2 AND 
      ds.DTMTRADEDATE <= GETDATE() AND
      STRSALETYPE IN ('I', 'T');
```

Comment: That was awfuly fast.